# Does VPN really protect IP address?

Tags: vpn

I have tried a VPN on ipad from Onavo.

When trying different websites giving IP address to my surprise some were able to still show my ip address not the VPN address.

So is VPN really worth as it slows down traffic ?

Comment: Which one was able to still track you?

Comment: It really looks like Onavo is not a standard VPN service. they don't mention anonymity at all, focusing on bad url filtering and secure connections through wifi (necessary so kids at the coffee shop can't intercept your unencrypted traffic). This is not a typical VPN. try one that doesn't advertise itself as a service specifically for iDevices. As for whether its worth it, thats somthing only you can say.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the VPN works (not just Onavo, but the default client in windows 7 too).

I do not have experience with Onavo, but it seems they do what I always configure when setting up a VPN connection in Windows 7.

The option I'm talking about is called Remote gateway, in the network->Ip-v4 settings.

This checkbox basically changes how internet traffic is routed. Instead of tunnelling everything over the VPN, it will only do so if the network can't find the server and then tries it over the VPN connection. The benefit of doing this is that you aren't sending the same data over the internet twice, and thus using double as much bandwidth.

The downside is that internet surfing goes over your own connection rather than the VPN one.

So it depends on how the VPN is configured. If configured properly, it'll be secure.